# How to specify invalid Path Attributes in BGP Packets [Scapy]

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, bgp

I am using Scapy to capture packets and modify one of the BGP packets and replay it to the routers. We are testing a vulnerability in our routers. For this, I need to set the Path Attributes to an invalid value and malform the packet to see how the router handles it. Like for eg: setting Local Preference to "-1" or to a value more than 2^32 or trying with any other attributes.

When trying this, Scapy gives a error message and doesn't run the script. Is there any way to achieve this using Scapy?